# ./configure generated Makefile requests for aclocal-1.11?

Tags: autotools, configure

I'm new with using autotools, and have a very serious problem I don't understand.
I wanted to test my new build system on an older machine, which is a Linux Kernel 2.4.18-64GB-SMP. I built the configure-script and other autotool-related files on a system with a kernel 3.1.9-2-ARCH.

This is what the run of "./configure" outputs:

```
$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
checking for gcc... colorgcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether colorgcc accepts -g... yes
checking for colorgcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of colorgcc... gcc
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for main in -lrt... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... colorgcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking wchar.h usability... yes
checking wchar.h presence... yes
checking for wchar.h... yes
checking wctype.h usability... yes
checking wctype.h presence... yes
checking for wctype.h... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible realloc... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for setlocale... yes
checking for strchr... yes
checking for strcspn... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strrchr... yes
checking for strspn... yes
checking for strstr... yes
checking for strtol... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating src/project/Makefile
config.status: creating include/config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

Okay, then, when I want to run make, I'm getting this:

```
$ make
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/sh /home/bp/project.test/mi
ssing --run aclocal-1.11 
/home/bp/project.test/missing: aclocal-1.11: command not found
WARNING: `aclocal-1.11' is missing on your system.  You should only need it if
         you modified `acinclude.m4' or `configure.ac'.  You might want
         to install the `Automake' and `Perl' packages.  Grab them from
         any GNU archive site.
 cd . && /bin/sh /home/bp/project.test/missing --run automake-1.11 --f
oreign
/home/bp/project.test/missing: automake-1.11: command not found
WARNING: `automake-1.11' is missing on your system.  You should only need it if
         you modified `Makefile.am', `acinclude.m4' or `configure.ac'.
         You might want to install the `Automake' and `Perl' packages.
         Grab them from any GNU archive site.
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/sh /home/bp/project.test/mi
ssing --run autoconf
configure.ac:1: error: Autoconf version 2.68 or higher is required for this scri
pt
configure.ac:1: the top level
make: *** [configure] Error 1
```

after that, running "make" again builds the sources. But the "configure" script and also the "aclocal.m4" script became zero-byte files.

```
-rwxrwxr-x    1 bp    users       33918 Jan 20 13:48 config.status
-rwxrwxr-x    1 bp    users           0 Jan 20 13:48 configure
-rw-rw-r--    1 bp    users           0 Jan 20 13:48 aclocal.m4
-rw-rw-r--    1 bp    users       22165 Jan 20 13:48 Makefile.in
```

What can I do? I thought that the configure-script the GNU autotools generate are platform independent and don't require the autotools to run?

Any ideas?

Comment: The Linux kernel versions are irrelevant, what is relevant is that the "old" system doesn't have the correct version of the autotools. Install them and it will work better.

Comment: Hello, but I thought the target system won't require the autotools?

Comment: I can't install autotools on my old system. And every manual about autotools states, that the configure-script builds platform indepentent Makefiles that don't require autotools installed.

Comment: The empty configure and aclocal.m4 scripts is because the makefile tried to recreate them, but since it failed those are empty. If you do the same copying like you did to the old machine, but locally on the new, will it behave the same there? Maybe you are missing a file in the copying?

Comment: Ahhh thank you, I've got it. The file "aclocal.m4" was missing!

Comment: I resolved it by doing a "make maintainer-clean", then checked all unknown files of the Mercurial repository ... yep, aclocal.m4 was missing. After adding it, the configure worked as expected, also on my old machine. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Autogenerated files should not be part of the repository, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865093/should-a-configure-script-be-distributed-if-configure-ac-is-available

Comment: @jørgensen is right. Specifically, that means that you _do_ need autotools on the target system if you are building from a repository. You _don't_ need them if you are building from a tarball.

Comment: Not a big deal since that's likely to be a developer as well if he grabs from SCM :)

Answer (score 2):

If your tarballs are trying to run `aclocal` and other autotools, it means there's something wrong with the tarball. Make sure your tarballs come from `make distcheck`.